# if statement process twice?

Tags: c, if-statement

I'm a beginner at C++, and I'm trying to do an exercise on ifs inside ifs.

First image: http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/5851/b9qt.jpg
   No else if statement so it was posted twice, but why does it have the wrong logic? The second statement posted is correct, though. o_o

Second image: http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/1351/94bc.jpg
   Used else if statements this time, posted once, but wrong logic. I've analysed the code over and over, and I can't find anything wrong with it. XD
   Shouldn't the logic used belong under the last statement? o_o

```
int number1, number2, number3, number4, number5;

printf("\n\n First number: ");
scanf("%d", &number1);
printf("\n Second number: ");
scanf("%d", &number2);
printf("\n Third number: ");
scanf("%d", &number3);
printf("\n Fourth number: ");
scanf("%d", &number4);
printf("\n Fifth number: ");
scanf("%d", &number5);

if (number3 >= number4 && number5) {
    if (number4 >= number5) {
    printf("\n\n Your numbers have been sorted: ");
    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d.", number1, number2, number3, number4, number5);

    printf("\n\n\n Program will now terminate..");
    } else if (number5 >= number4) {
    printf("\n\n Your numbers have been sorted: ");
    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d.", number1, number2, number3, number5, number4);

    printf("\n\n\n Program will now terminate..");
    } else {
    printf("\n\n Invalid operation. Program will now terminate..");
    }
} else if (number4 >= number3 && number5) {
    if (number3 >= number5) {
    printf("\n\n Your numbers have been sorted: ");
    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d.", number1, number2, number4, number3, number5);

    printf("\n\n\n Program will now terminate..");
    } else if (number5 >= number3) {
    printf("\n\n Your numbers have been sorted: ");
    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d.", number1, number2, number4, number5, number3);

    printf("\n\n\n Program will now terminate..");
    } else {
    printf("\n\n Invalid operation. Program will now terminate..");
    }
} else if (number5 >= number3 && number4) {
    if (number3 >= number4) {
    printf("\n\n Your numbers have been sorted: ");
    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d.", number1, number2, number5, number3, number4);

    printf("\n\n\n Program will now terminate..");
    } else if (number4 >= number3) {
    printf("\n\n Your numbers have been sorted: ");
    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d.", number1, number2, number5, number4, number3);

    printf("\n\n\n Program will now terminate..");
    } else {
    printf("\n\n Invalid operation. Program will now terminate..");
    }
} else {
    printf("\n\n Invalid operation. Program will now terminate..");
}
```

Comment: Logical operators don't work like that.

Comment: scanf and printf in C++ ? Why would you do that to yourself ?

Comment: I don't get the first two remarks. o_o

As for the last one, I was only allowed to use those, as well as only if and else statements. o_o; (I don't know either, but prolly because this lesson is from like a basic basic intro to prog. o_o)

Comment: If you want to sort numbers, I have to say this is possibly one of the worst ways to do it, definitely worse than bubble sort (at least bubble sort works for more than 5 elements). Look up [sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) and try implementing one of those (start with something like [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort)). Don't worry, you will get plenty of exercise with conditionals when implementing sorting algorithms, and it would actually be useful for more than 5 elements.

Comment: you are lucky that you only have 5 numbers

Comment: As it is not using anything specific to C++, I've removed the tag.

Comment: The first remark says that, in contrast to the English language, you can't say "if x is greater than 4 and 5". You'll have to express that as something like "if x is greater than 4 and x is greater than 5".

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty terrible way to solve this problem, but you'll get to the point of understanding why later as you keep learning. For now, as an exercise in understanding if statements, one problem is that

```
if(number3 >= number4 && number5) {
    ...
}
```

doesn't do what you think it does. It's actually interpreted more like

```
if( (number3 >= number4) && (number5) )
```

Note that `number5` out there alone. C++ lets you say things like

```
bool someFlag = true;
if(someFlag) { ... }
```

as a shorthand for

```
if(someFlag == true)
```

Combine this with the fact that in C++ (and C), any number can be treated like a boolean value. That is,

```
int x = 42;
int y = 0;
if(x) {
    printf("x is true\n");
}
if(y) {
    printf("y is true\n");
}
```

This code would print "x is true", but not "y is true", because 0 is considered false when interpreted as a boolean, and any other number is true.

So going back to your original code, you have

```
if(number3 <= number4 && number5)
```

This is two different boolean comparisons, and the if statement is true if both parts are true. Part 1 is `(number3 <= number4)` which you already understand. Part 2 is just `number5`, which obeys the same rules I just described.

What you need to say is

```
if(number3 <= number4 && number3 <= number5)
```

There's no short notation for that.

Comment: Well, he could define a min function/macro and do `if (number3 <= min(number4,number5))`. That's cheating a bit because there's still a comparison there, but if number3 is your critical data dependency it might be more efficient). Still - good explanation.

Comment: Thank you for telling me that. I'll go at it now. XD

Comment: @Leeor, Well, that already exists in `<algorithm>`. You can even say `if (number3 == std::min({number3, number4, number5}))`.

Comment: @chris, I missed the c++ part as he tagged it as c... nonetheless, the comparisons are still hiding there. Besides, that's nitpicking :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your logical operations inside the `if` statements. The syntax is correct, but the result is not what you would expect. This statement checks if `number3` is greater equal `number4` and is 1 if `true`. Then this result will applied to the next logical operation. Say `number3 >= number4` is true and `number5` is >0, then the whole expression is `true`.

```
number3 >= number4 && number5
```

Therefore, this does not check if `number3` is greater equal `number4` and greater equal `number5`. 
Instead, you have to write

```
(number3 >= number4) && (number3 >= number5)
```

and is `true` if `number3` is indeed greater equal `number4` and `number5`.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I'll change them!

Comment: @MalachyPasteur if deong's or my contribution helped you to understand the problem, you might take into account marking one of the answers as "accepted" so it becomes clear that the problem is solved.